# Hibernate HQL query extract missing ids entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I think that the title of the question might be misunderstood, so I'll explain all the workflow.

I have a [select2](https://select2.github.io/) which allows me to find all the missing document numbers from a documents list controller in the back-end. Atm I've implemented a method in which hibernate returns me the current documents list and, by iterating it, the method populates another list with a "fake" document with the missing number.

I wanted to know if it is possibile to translate this workflow in an HQL query which returns me back a new list of documents with the missing numbers.

**EXAMPLE**:

Base table:

```
| id | number |
---------------
| 1  | 1      |
---------------
| 8  | 3      |
---------------
| 9  | 4      |
---------------
| 12 | 8      |
```

My Select2 will receive back a `documentsList` like this

```
{ 
  model: {id: 2, number: 2},
  model: {id: 5, number: 5}
  model: {id: 6, number: 6}
  model: {id: 7, number: 7}
}
```

I hope this question is clear enough,
Thanks everyone in advance

**EDIT 2016/05/02**

This is the code I've implemented.

`HQLQueryProperties` is a class I've created to setup the HQL query executed by the DAO, which is called by the service (It's a Struts2 + Hibernate + Spring application). Anyway this part is not so important, since the DAO can execute normal HQLQueries or extract the query from the `HQLQueryProperties` object

```
HQLQueryProperties invoicesProperties = new HQLQueryProperties();
    Map<String, Object> invoicesAttributes = invoicesProperties
        .addJoinAttributes("documentType")
         .addWhereAttribute("listByOperationYear", "and", null)
         .addWhereAttribute("listByDocumentTypeId", "and", null)
         .addWhereAttribute("listByFacilityIds", "and", null)
         .addWhereAttribute("excludeNumbers", "and", null)
         .addQueryAttribute("operationYear", ((Map<String, Object>) session.get("operationYear")).get("selectedYear"))
         .addQueryAttribute("documentTypeId", documentTypeId)
         .addQueryAttribute("facilityIds", -1, ((Facility) session.get("facility")).getId())
         .addQueryAttribute("numbers", -1)
         .buildAttributes();
```

The paginator is another class I've created to setup the resulting jsp with a table which can be customized by the user which interact with this object. The method `getItems()` calls the required service/DAO and returns a `List<MyClass>` of items. It's also used to paginate the Select2 results

```
Paginator paginator = new Paginator("documentHeaderService", servletContext, getColumns("documentHeaderService"), invoicesAttributes, false);
paginator.setPerPage(-1);
paginator.setOrderColumn("number");

List<DocumentHeader> tempDocuments = paginator.getItems();
```

And here is the tricky part where I iterate over the collection in order to retrieve the missing number.

```
int currentNumber = 1;

for (DocumentHeader tempDocument : tempDocuments) {
    while (currentNumber < tempDocument.getNumber()) {
        freeNumbersList.add(new DocumentHeader(currentNumber));
        currentNumber++;
    }

    currentNumber++;
}
```

Comment: Use : query = from base table t where t.number = :value; query.setParameter("value", 0); or null or " " .

Comment: Can you add your current code please? I would like to have a better context about your question.

Comment: @hmrojas.p I've added the code

Comment: I think you could use a store procedure, so you call it on your Java code.